# ProxyPass ! directive not working

Tags: apache, tomcat7, mod-proxy

I am in the middle of migrating a server and my old virtual host config was like this

```
ProxyPass /images !
ProxyPass / ajp://domain.tld:8010/ nocanon
```

It passes ok to Tomcat but the ! directive is being ignored.  There are no errors thrown.  What might be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

If the `/images` rule matches but the path is not valid, e.g. cannot be found, Apache will try the next rule.

Only if all other rules are failing too, the first matched rule is used (and the corresponding error is shown, e.g. 404 instead of proxy error).